# subset data frame based on condition pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe as shown below

```
Contract_ID    Unit_ID    Start_date     End_Date     Status
1              A          2014-05-01     2015-05-01   Closed
2              A          2016-05-01     2017-05-01   Expired
3              A          2018-05-01     2020-05-01   Active
4              B          2014-05-01     2015-05-01   Closed
5              B          2015-05-01     2016-05-01   Closed
6              C          2016-05-01     2017-05-01   Closed
7              C          2017-05-01     2018-05-01   Expired
8              D          2016-05-01     2017-05-01   Closed
9              D          2017-06-01     2018-05-01   Expired
10             D          2018-07-01     2020-08-01   Active
```

From the above I would like to find out the Units which does not have status active.

From the above table Unit A and D has active status.

Expected output

```
Contract_ID    Unit_ID    Start_date     End_Date     Status
4              B          2014-05-01     2015-05-01   Closed
5              B          2015-05-01     2016-05-01   Closed
6              C          2016-05-01     2017-05-01   Closed
7              C          2017-05-01     2018-05-01   Expired
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First idea is filter all groups if no value `Active` per groups by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.all.html):

```
df1 = df[df.assign(New=df['Status'].ne('Active')).groupby('Unit_ID')['New'].transform('all')]
```

Or first filter all groups where is at least one `Active` by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and then filter by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with inverted mask groups with no `Active` groups:

```
df1 = df[~df['Unit_ID'].isin(df.loc[df['Status'].eq('Active'), 'Unit_ID'])]

print (df1)
   Contract_ID Unit_ID  Start_date    End_Date   Status
3            4       B  2014-05-01  2015-05-01   Closed
4            5       B  2015-05-01  2016-05-01   Closed
5            6       C  2016-05-01  2017-05-01   Closed
6            7       C  2017-05-01  2018-05-01  Expired
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach with [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) and [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)

```
new_df = df[df['Unit_ID'].map(pd.crosstab(df['Unit_ID'],df['Status'])['Active'].eq(0))]
```

or with [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html)

```
new_df = df[df['Status'].ne('Active').groupby(df['Unit_ID']).transform('all')]
```

**Output**

```
   Contract_ID Unit_ID  Start_date    End_Date   Status
3            4       B  2014-05-01  2015-05-01   Closed
4            5       B  2015-05-01  2016-05-01   Closed
5            6       C  2016-05-01  2017-05-01   Closed
6            7       C  2017-05-01  2018-05-01  Expired
```